# Is it safe to assume that if $y$ is a real number and $y > 0$, that there exists a real number $x$ such that $a^x = y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I used this assummption to count the number of real solutions for $\left||x^2-1|-1\right| = 2^x$ and I got the same number of solutions that my textbook got using plotting. Are there any cases where this assumption does not hold?

Comment: You also require that $a>0$ and $a\neq 1$.

Comment: And if @JMoravitz's conditions hold, just put $x=\ln y/\ln a$.

Comment: Thank you both. I didn't even think about the restrictions on $a$ because in my problem it was $2$. Can we assume that there is only one such $x$? I wondered about this while solving the problem because of the quadratic term.

Comment: Yes, there is only ever one such $x$.  This can be seen by noting that $a^x$ is a continuous monotonic function (*monotonic increasing if $a>1$ and monotonic decreasing if $a<1$*).  Equivalently by using logarithms and noting that logarithms are well defined functions for the domain... and functions are by their very definition single-valued.

Comment: the exponential function is monotonic, hence yes, your assumption holds